# Angular, using ngForm and EventEmitters, variable always one step behind

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

in one of my components, I need to set a variable equal to another variable I am using as an HTML attribute/ angular directive...

In this components HTML I have the following code -

```
<div>
  <app-myapp> [object]="myobject" (validate)="setAsValid($event)"> ....
```

the `setAsValid` method just sets a variable as true or false, then calls a `handleChanges` method which should set another variable as `myobject` (which should be retrieved from *myapp*)

```
setAsValid(ev: boolean) {
    this.isValid = ev;
    this.handleChanges();
  }

handleChanges() {
    if (this.myobject) {
      this.parent.object = JSON.stringify(this.myobject);
    }
  }
```

so I have a `myobject` variable in this components typescript, and am linking it to [object]...

in *myapp.component.ts* I have object declared as so -

```
@Input() object: Object;
@Output() validate = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
@ViewChild(NgForm) form;
```

`Object` is declared as so :

```
export class Object {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  innerObject: InnerObject;
}
```

and inside the `innerObject` there is a variable which is a list of strings.

```
export class InnerObject {
  extras : string[];
}
```

Now, inside *myApp* html, I am implementing another app component, called string-list

````
<app-string-list (valuesChange)="validateModel()"
        [(values)]="object.innerObject.extras" [label]="'Add Extra'"
        [placeholder]="'Extras'"></app-string-list>```
````

and the `validateModel` function is just calling the `EventEmitter`

```
validateModel() {
    this.validate.emit(this.form.valid);
  }
```

`valuesChange` is declared in *string-list-component.ts* -

this is how that class is set up -

```
class Elem {
  val: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-string-list',
  templateUrl: './string-list.component.html',
})
export class StringListComponent implements OnInit {
  _elems: Elem[];

  @Input()
  label = 'Add';

  @Input()
  placeholder: String;

  @Input()
  style = '';

  @Input()
  get values(): string[] {
    return this._elems.map(e => e.val);
  }

  private subject = new Subject();

  @Output()
  valuesChange = new EventEmitter();

  set values(val: string[]) {
    this._elems = val.map(v => <Elem>{'val': v, 'name': UUID.UUID(), 'style': this.style});
  }

  notifyUpdate(val: string[]) {
    this.valuesChange.emit(this._elems.map(e => e.val).filter(val => val && val.trim().length > 0));
    this.subject.next();
  }

  trackByFn(index) {
    return index;
  }

  add() {
    if (!this._elems) {
      this._elems = [];
    }

    this._elems.push(new Elem());
  }

  delete(index) {
    this._elems.splice(index, 1);
    this.notifyUpdate();
    this.valuesChange.emit(this._elems.map(e => e.val));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public onChange() {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

my problem here, is that whenever I make a change in the string list component, my changes are logged into the variables within that class, however, in the first component I posted above, `myobject` is always one step behind.

In other words, if I add one letter to that string-list element within that component on the page, the top parent component that is trying to get that component with

```
[object]="myobject"
```

will fail because `myobject` will still be the same string it was before, then if I erase that letter I added, `myobject` will have that letter at the end of it. so `myobject` is always one step behind what the current string within the element is in string-list component.

I am trying to figure out what is causing this disconnect and how to fix it without doing a huge refactor.

Comment: can you provide us with stackblitz link to reproduce your problem ?

Comment: this is way too match for us to figure out without a sample. It not clear what is the component relations in your question. If this is still a problem, update your question.